# PHP: If not selecting correctly

Tags: php, if-statement

I am building a list based off of a CSV file. Here are the two most common lines in the CSV file:

```
10,11,12,13,14,15,16    
12,13,14,15,16,0,0
```

The file is read line-by-line and stored into the list. Here is the code:

```
while(($current_line = fgets($find_products, 4096)) !== false) {
    list($weight1, $weight2, $weight3, $weight4, $weight5, $weight6, $weight7) = explode(",", $current_line);
}
```

I look at the value of each item in the list, and print if the value is not 0. Here is the code:

```
if($weight1 != '0') {
    print '<option>'.$weight1.' lb.</option>';
}

if($weight2 != '0') {
    print '<option>'.$weight2.' lb.</option>';
}

if($weight3 != '0') {
    print '<option>'.$weight3.' lb.</option>';
}

if($weight4 != '0') {
    print '<option>'.$weight4.' lb.</option>';
}

if($weight5 != '0') {
    print '<option>'.$weight5.' lb.</option>';
}

if($weight6 != '0') {
    print '<option>'.$weight6.' lb.</option>';
}

if($weight7 != '0') {
    print '<option>'.$weight7.' lb.</option>';
}
```

Here are the results of the code after it is run on a CSV file with the above two lines:

```
10 lb.
11 lb.
12 lb.
13 lb.
14 lb.
15 lb.
16 lb.
```

AND

```
12 lb.
13 lb.
14 lb.
15 lb.
16 lb.
0 lb.
```

The 0 lb. should not be showing up based on the value of $weight6 and $weight7. I have printed the values of these two variables, and they appropriately show up as 0. I can also confirm through testing that the if-statement for $weight7 is the culprit, but I have no idea what is causing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this could be written with 90% less lines --

Comment: Why not `foreach (explode(",", $current_line) as $weight) { if ($weight != '0') { } }`?

Comment: Did you try a `var_dump($weight7);` to see it's type? It may give you a clue.

Comment: @Dagon
Thanks for the useful information. I will look into how to reduce the line usage ;).

Comment: @Marty
There is a lot more code involved that is not shown. All the rest of it works. The weights are the only things acting weird.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the exact same test case.

Comment: var_dump($weight7);
string '0' (length=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `fgets()` returns the line with a newline at the end. So `$weight7` is `"0\r\n"` (that's why `var_dump` says the length is 3), not `"\0"`. You should trim the line before you split it, to remove this.

```
while(($current_line = fgets($find_products, 4096)) !== false) {
    $current_line = trim($current_line);
    list($weight1, $weight2, $weight3, $weight4, $weight5, $weight6, $weight7) = explode(",", $current_line);
}
```

Or you could instead use `fgetcsv()` rather than `fgets()`. It automatically trims the line and splits it at the separator, returning an array that you can iterate over.

```
while ($weights = fgetcsv($find_products)) {
    foreach ($weights as $w) {
        if ($w != '0') {
            echo "<option>$w lb.</option>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That made all the dropdowns work correctly. Thanks for explaining why it was working as such!